# Cant load DLL when copied to other computer

Tags: java, windows, dll, java-native-interface

I have built [Mecab.dll](http://taku910.github.io/mecab/) using **Visual Studio 2017 Community Build tools** and able to load in Java using JNI. When I copy the DLL to other computer and try to load in java, it does work.

Dependency Walker shows that it uses some DLL file from **Visual Studio Build Tools** which are not available on the other computer as it's not a development machine.

[image]

How can I build the DLL so that I can use it on any other machine without installing Visual Studio/Build Tools? I'm from a Java background and have no clue how to do this? Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that Dependency Walker often gives red herrings. You haven't given us quite enough to go on, but I'll offer some theories that may help you:

- Try installing the [Visual Studio redist packages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)
- You have built the DLL as a "Debug" build.  This is usually not portable to systems that do not have the same Visual Studio version, as the supporting DLLs are not installed.
- Your copied DLL is not trusted.  See if the file is blocked, and if so [unblock it](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/this-file-is-potentially-unsafe-to-open-need/b4038008-de01-44cc-8759-38970488b47b)
- You aren't making the correct System.load() or System.loadLibrary() call to find the DLL in its copied place. Unfortunately, these methods can report success and still not be able to access your native methods.
- You haven't put the DLL in the PATH.

Hopefully one of these will get you unstuck. If not, please post your error stack trace and messages so we can help you.

Comment: Hi Wheezil, thanks for your reply. #1, #3,4,5 all looks good. It could be #2.

Following are the flags used in the compiler & linker commands. Do I've to change anything to make it "Release" build?

CFLAGS = /EHsc /O2 /GL /GA /Ob2 /nologo /W3 /MT /Zi /wd4800 /wd4305 /wd4244
LDFLAGS = /nologo /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /LTCG /NXCOMPAT /DYNAMICBASE /MACHINE:X64 ADVAPI32.LIB
CFLAGS = /EHsc /O2 /GL /GA /Ob2 /nologo /W3 /MT /Zi /wd4800 /wd4305 /wd4244
LDFLAGS = /nologo /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /LTCG /NXCOMPAT /DYNAMICBASE /MACHINE:X64 ADVAPI32.LIB

Comment: I am not sure how to do this on the linker command-line.  I've always picked up the correct dependencies by choosing "Release" vs "Debug" build in Visual Studio, via the header includes, which have #pragma lines that inject dependencies into the .obj files which eventually the linker processes. I believe, but am unsure, that this comes from the presence or absence of preprocessor variables like NDEBUG.  Good luck!